# IIS configuration logs to Event viewer system logs

Tags: iis, event-viewer

I have enabled IIS configuration [Operational] logs and I am able to view the appropriate changes in event viewer under IIS-Configuration directory.

However, these logs are not being compiled by Windows System logs present in event viewer. Please help.